# Jordan matrices with the only eigenvalue $1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

So, I need to list all of the Jordan matrices of a $4x4$ matrix with the only eigenvalue $1$. If the only eigenvalue is 1, then there can't be any other value on the diagonal, correct? So am I wrong in thinking that only Jordan matrix would be this? $$ J_{1,n} =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Why wouldn't $I_4$ be a jordan matrix?

Comment: You would be right in thinking that matrix is **one** of the possibilities, but you're wrong if you think that is the only one (up to order of the Jordan blocks, of course).

Comment: @Timbuc So if every diagonal matrix is a Jordan matrix but all of the eigenvalues are the same, is it the $I_4$ matrix and this one? or can some of the values on the diagonal be zero?

Comment: There are five possibilities: $4=1+1+1+1$, $4=1+1+2$, $4=1+3$, $4=2+2$, $4=4$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read egreg's comment and complete. Some of the possibilities are:

$$\begin{align}&4=4\;\;\rightarrow&\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&4=3+1\;\;\rightarrow&\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\\{}\\
&4=2+2\;\;\rightarrow&\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&1\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\end{align}$$

Can you see the relation? $\;4=n+k+r=$ one block of size $\;n\;$ and one of size $\;k\;$ and one of size $\;r\;$ (and etc.), and thus, by the comment quoted before, there are as many possibilities as *partitions* of $\;4\;$ , which are five.

Complete now according to the other partitions.

Comment: Ohhhh okay. This is what I started to do after I saw his comment but I didn't know why it was this way. Thanks you really cleared it up.

Comment: @SofiaJune My pleasure. This way, with partitions, really makes it much easier to cover all the possibilities, indeed.